# Get A Threaded Message by Recipients

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have database schemas like this:

```
users
USERNAME (PK), SEX
Alex, F
John, M
Troy, M
Matt, M

messages
ID (PK), CREATOR (FK users), DATE_CREATED
1, John, 2012-04-15
2, Troy, 2012-04-16

message_recipients
ID, MESSAGE_ID (FK messages), RECIPIENT (FK users), DATE
1, 1, John, 2012-04-15
2, 1, Troy, 2012-04-15
3, 1, Matt, 2012-04-15
4, 2, Alex, 2012-04-16
4, 2, John, 2012-04-16
```

The challenge is this, I want to get a message ID that has John, Troy and Matt as the recipients only.

This is my query:

```
SELECT mr1.MESSAGE_ID
FROM message_recipients mr1, message_recipients mr2
WHERE mr1.MESSAGE_ID = mr2.MESSAGE_ID
  AND mr1.RECIPIENT = mr2.RECIPIENT
  AND mr2.RECIPIENT = 'John'
  AND mr2.RECIPIENT = 'Troy'
  AND mr2.RECIPIENT = 'Matt'
```

The SQL above shows No Results.

If I do this query:

```
SELECT mr1.MESSAGE_ID
FROM message_recipients mr1, message_recipients mr2
WHERE mr1.MESSAGE_ID = mr2.MESSAGE_ID
  AND mr1.RECIPIENT_ID = mr2.RECIPIENT_ID
  AND (mr2.RECIPIENT_ID = 'John'
  OR mr2.RECIPIENT_ID = 'Troy'
  OR mr2.RECIPIENT_ID = 'Matt')
GROUP BY mr1.MESSAGE_ID
```

The results:

```
MESSAGE_ID
1
2
```

The above results are incorrect because what I want to see is only 1 (MESSAGE_ID) as the result.

What did I do wrong? Could someone enlighten me?

Thank you very much,
    John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you want. But a column can't be 3 things. You can just the `IN` syntax . Like this:

```
SELECT mr1.MESSAGE_ID
FROM message_recipients mr1, message_recipients mr2
WHERE mr1.MESSAGE_ID = mr2.MESSAGE_ID
  AND mr1.RECIPIENT = mr2.RECIPIENT
  AND mr2.RECIPIENT IN('John','Troy','Matt')
```

Or the `OR` syntax like this:

```
SELECT mr1.MESSAGE_ID
    FROM message_recipients mr1, message_recipients mr2
    WHERE mr1.MESSAGE_ID = mr2.MESSAGE_ID
      AND mr1.RECIPIENT = mr2.RECIPIENT
      AND 
      (
      mr2.RECIPIENT = 'John'
      OR mr2.RECIPIENT = 'Troy'
      OR mr2.RECIPIENT = 'Matt'
      )
```

**EDIT**

I am still not sure what you want. But it kinda sound like you want something like this:

```
SELECT
    m.ID AS MESSAGE_ID,
    m.CREATOR,
    mr.RECIPIENT,
    mr2.RECIPIENT
FROM
    messages AS m
    LEFT JOIN message_recipients AS mr
        ON m.ID=mr.MESSAGE_ID
        AND mr.RECIPIENT='Troy'
    LEFT JOIN message_recipients AS mr2
        ON m.ID=mr2.MESSAGE_ID
        AND mr2.RECIPIENT='Matt'
WHERE
    m.CREATOR='John'
```

Comment: I have tried this too, but it gives '2' as the result as well. Not really what I want.

Comment: Can you update the question and supply that output you expect?

Comment: I have updated the question and the output I expect. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks Arion, I have used your last post as a guideline to get the results I wanted.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. @user1302607 : Remember to up vote the answers you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling :P

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Use `OR` instead of `AND`

Try below :

```
SELECT mr1.MESSAGE_ID
FROM message_recipients mr1 LEFT JOIN message_recipients mr2 
ON mr1.MESSAGE_ID = mr2.MESSAGE_ID
WHERE  mr1.RECIPIENT = mr2.RECIPIENT
  AND ( mr2.RECIPIENT = 'John'
  OR mr2.RECIPIENT = 'Troy'
  OR mr2.RECIPIENT = 'Matt')
```

Comment: Try to use left join instead of simple join. Try query posted here

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try-

```
SELECT mr1.MESSAGE_ID
FROM message_recipients mr1, message_recipients mr2
WHERE mr1.MESSAGE_ID = mr2.MESSAGE_ID
  AND mr1.RECIPIENT = mr2.RECIPIENT
  AND mr2.RECIPIENT = 'John'
  AND mr2.RECIPIENT in ('Troy','Matt')
```